# Proper naming for objects which have a position and bounds on a plane

Tags: inheritance, interface, kotlin, mixins, trait

I have an `interface` which is for an object which has *bounds* in a 2D plane.

```
interface Boundable : Positionable {

    /**
     * Returns the [Bounds] (the [Position] and [Size]) of this [Boundable].
     */
    fun bounds(): Bounds

    /**
     * Returns the [Size] of this [Boundable].
     */
    fun size(): Size

    /**
     * Tells whether this [Boundable] intersects the other `boundable` or not.
     */
    fun intersects(boundable: Boundable): Boolean

    /**
     * Tells whether `position` is within this boundable's bounds.
     */
    fun containsPosition(position: Position): Boolean

    /**
     * Tells whether this boundable contains the other `boundable`.
     * A [Boundable] contains another if the other boundable's bounds
     * are within this one's. (If their bounds are the same it is considered
     * a containment).
     */
    fun containsBoundable(boundable: Boundable): Boolean
}
```

This is something like `Rect` in the *Java* SDK for example. Currently `Boundable` inherits from `Positionable`:

```
/**
 * Represents an object which is positionable within its parent.
 * Note that once positioned a [Positionable] can't be moved.
 * If you want re-positionable objects @see [Movable].
 */
interface Positionable {

    fun position(): Position = Position.zero()

}
```

`Positionable` is for objects which have a `Position` within a larger object on the same plane. This setup worked so far but now I need to have *3 versions* of `Boundable`. One, which does not inherit from `Positionable` (to be used for detached or root objects), one which does and one which is `Movable`:

```
/**
 * A [Movable] object is a specialized [Positionable].
 * It can not only be positioned but moved as well.
 */
interface Movable : Positionable {

    fun moveTo(position: Position): Boolean

    fun moveBy(position: Position) = moveTo(position() + position)

    fun moveRightBy(delta: Int) = moveTo(position().withRelativeX(delta))

    fun moveLeftBy(delta: Int) = moveTo(position().withRelativeX(-delta))

    fun moveUpBy(delta: Int) = moveTo(position().withRelativeY(-delta))

    fun moveDownBy(delta: Int) = moveTo(position().withRelativeY(delta))
}
```

My problem is figured out a name for the variants, but I'm not satisfied with them. I came up with `PositionableBoundable` and `MovableBoundable` but they sound weird.

*Are these names adequate or should I change them to something more descriptive?*

Answer (score 2):

#### Everything is an Entity!

If you would follow the [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) approach, that is. The idea is that all *objects* are *entities*, and each Entity has several *components*. Size, Position, Movable - all this are different aspects of what an Entity possibly could do and are therefore each it's own `Component`. As for Systems, that's where most of the logic is.

Names like `PositionableBoundable` and `MovableBoundable` sound weird because it is weird, you are trying to use one name for two things. *Composition over inheritance* is the key here.

As for the name `Boundable`, I would probably have gone for just `Box` or `Rect` which are more well known.

Comment: I agree that an ECS is a solution here but I'm working on a library and I'd like to have explicit responsibilities for my objects so it is easier to use and reason about for my users. In my model `Rect` is `Bounds`. `Boundable` is an object which *has* bounds but they can change (therefore `Bounds` is immutable). This model works pretty well because I'm using Kotlin's delegation feature (the `by` keyword). So what you are saying that I should just have a `Boundable` (or whatever it will be renamed to) and have my implementors implement `Positionable` and `Movable` individually?

Comment: I'm working on an UI toolkit and I already have a [`Box`](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/363771631727804416/495339182412136469/unknown.png) sadly.

Comment: @AdamArold I can't say much more without looking at more of your code and knowing more about your goal with the library.

Comment: Here is the lib: https://github.com/Hexworks/zircon

Comment: And the `Boundable`: https://github.com/Hexworks/zircon/blob/master/zircon.core/src/main/kotlin/org/hexworks/zircon/api/behavior/Boundable.kt